# USB device not found if I run the Android project

Tags: android

I have installed 'Google USB driver' in sdk manager.

I have checked the USB debugging mode in my mobile under 'developer options' of 
settings. I have also verified the connections between mobile and pc, no problem.

I have set the edit configuration to USB device too.

If I run the project I get the error stating ' USB device not found'
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Open Device Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-device-manager#1TC=windows-7)
2. Look for your phone, it should have a yellow warning sign next to it
3. Select update/install driver
4. Select brose my computer
5. Let me pick a list of device drivers on my computer
6. Select ADB interface nad select one of google's ADB's if you don't have manufacturer specific ones. If you do not see ADB interface here, then skip to link.
7. Select ok, ignore warning and you are good to go.

I have found a tutorial with screenshots [HERE](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/manualinstall.php)

Comment: The tutorial you have mentioned  under 'here' helped.

Comment: Also if the **ADB interface** does not show up in the device list, you can manually install the driver by right-clicking "android_winusb.inf" in google usb driver folder and clicking "Install".